# Group typo3 condition

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I need such a condition in ts:

```
([treeLevel = 0] && [globalVar = GP:R > 0]) || [PIDinRootline = {$pages.2018}]
```

I wanna show block if page has treelevel=0 and the get var R > 0, or if page id = $pages.2018
It looks like the similar code in php:

```
if(($treeLevel == 0 && $r > 0) || (pid == number))
```

The all expression in first brackets should be right, or in second.
Is it exist the method to group it like the previous record or I can only use userfunc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no grouping in TS conditions, but if you need this particular condition from your post I think it is not needed because brackets around && are useless in this case.

```
(p && q) || r
```

is exactly the same as

```
p && q || r
```

Did you tested it?

Comment: I think my answer is still valid. Please take a look here, it works exactly in the way as you want to, doesn't it? https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=p+%26%26+q+%7C%7C+r